# Como resolver esta superposicion del label con el contorno del Select? Es de material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material

El codigo funciona y no me marca ningun error, pero no puedo resolver la superposicion de la label con el contorno del select, y no se cual es mi error. Una disculpa si es una pregunta muy basica, soy nuevo en React y estoy aprendiendo.

Les dejo una imagen del problema:

[image: Issue]

Este es mi codigo:

> Select:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import OutlinedInput from '@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import { MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 270,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
});

class NativeSelects extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      grupo: '',
      name: 'hai',
      labelWidth: 0,
    };


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      labelWidth: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.InputLabelRef).offsetWidth,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={classes.root}>

        <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel
            ref={ref => {
              this.InputLabelRef = ref;
            }}
            htmlFor="outlined-age-simple"
          >Selecciona un grupo</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.props.grupo}
            onChange={(e)=>this.props.handleChange(e.target.value)}
            input={
              <OutlinedInput
                name="grupo"
                labelWidth={this.labelWidth}
                id="outlined-age-simple"
              />
            }
          >
            <MenuItem value="" />
            <MenuItem value={1} >Fundamentos de Programacion</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={2} >Programacion Aplicada</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={3} >Taller de Desarrollo de Aplicaciones</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={4} >Seminario de Tecnologia</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={5} >Ingenieria de Circuitos</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={6} >Sistemas de Bases de Datos</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={7} >Programacion Orientada a Objetos</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={8} >Arquitectura de Software</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={9} >Desarrollo Web Avanzado</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

NativeSelects.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NativeSelects);
```

Mi idea es que no se atraviese la label en el contorno.
Aprovechando, pregunto una duda mas, se puede publicar codigo correcto en forma de pregunta?

Ejemplo, tengo esta duda pero la resolvi solo y no publique la pregunta antes, pero ya llegue a la solucion, puedo solo publicar mi solucion?

Muchas gracias a todos, continuo aprendiendo y practicando el uso de React!

Comment: Hola Erik, al parecer tu problema es más de css que de react y javascript, la solución a lo que te sucede puede estar relacionada con tus clases de css y estilos. No entiendo a qué te refieres con publicar código correcto a forma de pregunta, y sí, si tienes la solución a una pregunta que tu mismo realizaste en el sitio, siempre puedes responderla y así otras personas que tengan el mismo inconveniente que tu podrán tener más opciones de respuesta

Comment: Gracias German, de hecho no tengo ningun CSS, probablemente sea eso.

Comment: Me refiero, por ejemplo, si desarrollo un codigo para cualquier tipo de funcionalidad, que lo pueda publicar aqui no a modo de pregunta, sino a modo de "hice esto, espero les sirva". Eso se puede? Dando una breve descripcion de que hace, etc.

Comment: Hola Erik, cuando defines tu variable `style` estás definiendo algo que al final terminará en un archivo css cuando React haga el bundle, además, no solo son los estilos que tu mismo escribes, si no que pueden entrar en conflicto diferentes librerías que estés usando y que también hacen uso de su propio css. Y si, si fue lo que te ayudó a solucionar el problema puedes indicarlo tal cual como dices, eres libre de responderte a ti mismo y le servirá a otras personas que tengan el mismo inconveniente